# presenting contents of xml to table view

Tags: iphone, ios4

how do i present XML content on UITableview .

sample structure:

```
    </node>
        <node name="abcd" id="id:1">
        <node name="abcde" id="id:1"/>
    </node>
```

The structure in the table should be represented as below
abcd
 abcde

Comment: You should parse xml, load data to an array, and then use that array to lode data on the table.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, maybe you should be using the iPhone sdk 5.0... That being said, You need to parse your XML using an NSXMLParser object.

I've made a simple one while explaining it to a friend, and I've adapted it to work with your code. Here's the header:

```
@interface MyParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
  NSMutableArray *nodeArray;
}

+(NSArray*)parseNodeData:(NSData*)data;
-(NSArray*)nodes;
-(void)parseWithData:(NSData*)data;
@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation MyParser

+(NSArray*)parseNodeData:(NSData*)data {
  NSArray *ret;
  MyParser *parser = [[MyParser alloc] init];
  [parser parseWithData:data];
  ret = [parser nodes];
  [parser release];
  return(ret);
}

-(NSArray*)nodes {
  if (nodeArray == nil)
    return(nil);
  return([NSArray arrayWithArray:nodeArray]);
}

-(void)dealloc {
  [nodeArray release];

  [super dealloc];
}

-(void)parseWithData:(NSData*)data {
  NSXMLParser parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
  [parser setDelegate:self];
  [parser parse];
  [parser release];
}

#pragma mark - NSXMLParserDelegate methods
-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser*)parser {
  if (nodeArray != nil)
    [nodeArray release];

  nodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict {
  if ([elementName compare:@"node" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
    [nodeArray addObject[attributeDict valueForKey:@"name"]];
  }
}

@end
```

Use that code (it can be optimized -- a lot) to grab the information on your XML file and save it to an `NSArray`, store it on your UITableView and display the data.

Comment: my problem is we have two type of xmls which should be rendered to a table.we have a "level" field defined in the xml structure using which i am able to align the contents in the xml into the Tableview,where as in other there is no such field to identify which is causing a problem.how will i get rid of this.

Comment: Any chance you can add an example of this xml with the level parameter so I can change my answer to suit your needs?

Comment: the xml looks like this :                                           <books  title="ABCD" splitMode="byBookmarks">
    <books id="10"  name="abcd1" originalPage="1" level="1"/>
    <books id="11"  name="abcd2" originalPage="2" level="2"/>
    <books id="12"  name="abcd3" originalPage="2" level="2"/> 
    <books id="13"  name="abcd4" originalPage="3" level="2"/>
    <books id="14"  name="abcd5" originalPage="4" level="2"/>
    <books id="14"  name="abcd6" originalPage="4" level="3"/>
</books>The one which which i am suppose to use doesn't contain the level filed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following line ...

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/